# Is it possible for acceleration, velocity and position vectors to all be orthogonal?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

Is it possible for a moving particle to have position, velocity and acceleration vector components to all be orthogonal to one another? The formula below is in my textbook for the electric field of a moving point charge, and I think that the last term would always be zero because there are components of each type of vector in it. They would all have to be orthogonal to one another in order for the term to be non-zero, but I don't know of an instance where this could be true.

Is this possible, or am I interpreting this equation incorrectly?

I think that $\vec u$ is unique to my textbook so it is $\vec u = c\hat {\mathscr{r}}-\vec v$.

[image: Electric field for moving particle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mistaken. The cross product is $0$ when the vectors are parallel. The cross product is non-zero when they are not parallel. In other words, the vectors don't have to be orthogonal to have a non-zero cross product.

For example, if all three of those vectors were in the same plane but not parallel, that term is non-zero.

For a simple example:
$$\vec A=[1,2,0]$$
$$\vec B=[1,0,0]$$
$$\vec C=[2,1,0]$$

As you can see, none of these vectors are orthogonal. Yet
$$\vec B\times\vec C=[0,0,1]$$
$$\vec A\times(\vec B\times\vec C)=[2,-1,0]$$
Which is a non-zero result.

Comment: If I were to do some math and change the vectors (for position, velocity and acceleration) into unit vectors, then all for this term to not equal zero they would have to be orthogonal, correct? That was where my trouble came from, I know that the vectors don't always need to be orthogonal, but they cannot be parallel.

Comment: Edit to my above comment: I realize now that if I were to break up the vectors I could potentially get multiple unit vectors, which wouldn't leave me with zero for an answer to the cross product term.

Comment: @matryoshka All you need is one counter-example, which I have provided. The vectors do not need to be orthogonal. Glad I could help :)